# File copy, based on size

Tags: robocopy

My access .mde file gradually grows in size, starting at say 50Mb. I want to write a batch file that will copy and overwrite the file (with a clean version), when it grows beyond 10% (say 55Mb).

Unfortunately, RoboCopy's "\min:n" switch interogates the size of the source file/folder, not the destination file,otherwise this be the answer.

Can anyone help me with this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a batch script that will compare the file size to given constant and conditionally overwrite your `.mde` file. I am not very good at batch scripts, but I would go with smth like this:

create `overwrite.bat`:

```
@echo off
set FILESIZE=%~z1
echo %FILESIZE%
if %FILESIZE% lss 57671680 goto FINISH
echo overwriting from backup
copy /Y backup_folder\backup_file.mde .\your_file.mde
:FINISH
exit
```

then you can call

```
overwrite.bat your_file.mde
```

*note 57671680 is 55Mb as mentioned in your question*

Comment: SMC - adapted your code and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much